# Mathematical symbols in Mathematica and Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

How may I transfer mathematical text (with symbols, etc.) from Wolfram Mathematica into Stack Exchange?

Comment: AFAIK, Mathematica has a TeX output filter available

Comment: This belongs on Meta

Answer (score 6):

Try `TeXForm[]` in Mathematica.

```
TeXForm[Integrate[f(x), {x,-7,\[Pi]}]]
```

which outputs

```
\int_{-7}^{\pi } f(x) \, dx
```

Putting that between dollar signs on this page

```
$\int_{-7}^{\pi } f(x) \, dx$
```

yields $\int_{-7}^{\pi } f(x) \, dx$.  (footnote 1)  Between double dollar signs,
$$\int_{-7}^{\pi } f(x) \, dx \text{.}  $$

It's not perfect, and you may want to tweak the results, but it is an 80+% solution.

(footnote 1) There are several style faults in the form of integrals produced by Mathematica.  I would always style the given integral as `\int_{-7}^{\pi } \; f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x`, "$\int_{-7}^{\pi } \; f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$", but there are plenty of sources that can't be bothered to ensure the limits of integration and integrand don't collide and don't correctly render operators in an upright font.

Comment: $+1$. Every day we learn something new !!!.

Comment: Upright font for dx is the continental European convention, italic font is the US convention.

Comment: thanks; I was using wrong input format for TeXForm function. This clears that up, I think.

Comment: I often find myself simply right-clicking on the expression of interest and choose "Copy as LaTeX" from the context menu: https://s3.amazonaws.com/resources.gomodus.com/nb/latex.jpg